# Quickly cycle through fonts in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

Is there a method to quickly scroll through fonts to see what looks good when working with a UITextView in Storyboard?

Like in Photoshop I can just press the down arrow to quickly cycle through fonts and see one I like.    In Xcode it is a whole series of clicks to change the font and I just want to make sure I'm not missing something.

Thanks